# Which Truth should be revealed and which should be hidden?

Tags: dharma

- As in Mahabharata Lord krishna asked Yudishtra to Lie as his guru's son Aswathama was dead although it was a elephant it was a Lie,and it was for dharma.
- Yudishtra was not so willing to lie as it is adharma but as the lord alknowing said in that situation lie is good as for dharma

**QUESTION :**

- Lord Krishna was a god and so he was confident in that situation but as a conditioned soul how can we choose the path of telling and hiding a truth.

**EXAMPLE :**

- A women who has a daughter to be married has wrong affair with other man should be revealed or not ?
- If not revealed she would not be punished and she will continue to do adharma.
- If we reveal it then the family name will be completely destroyed and her daughter's marriage will not occur as everyone thinks as a mother same as the daughter.
- Or it should be revealed after her marriage and if later revealed it will be also like hiding?
- There many situations that arise while telling a truth.
- Is there any definite scriptural way to tell and hide the truth in the world?

Comment: There're no hard & fast rules .. so no definite scriptural way for when to speak truth or false. See: [satyaṃ brūyāt priyaṃ brūyānna brūyāt satyamapriyam |  priyaṃ ca nānṛtaṃ brūyādeṣa dharmaḥ sanātanaḥ || 138 ||](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200246.html)

Comment: [He shall say what is true; and he shall say what is agreeable; he shall not say what is true, but disagreeale; nor shall he say what is agreeable, but untrue; this is the eternal law.—(138)](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200246.html)

Comment: If you like @Rickross's answer, I suggest you make your question a very specific one instead of generic one such as now and flag to re-open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A women who has a daughter to be married has wrong affair with other
>   man should be revealed or not ?

In this case, the **father should reveal it**. Not doing so is actually a punishable deed.

> Manu Smriti 8.205. He who gives (a damsel in marriage), **having first
>   openly declared** her blemishes, whether she be insane, or afflicted
>   with leprosy, or **have lost her virginity, is not liable to punishment.**

**EDIT:**

.............

> Is there any definite scriptural way to tell and hide the truth in the
>   world?

Yes there are. Although speaking only truth and shunning falsehood is recommended for all people at all the times, but in some situations speaking falsehood is also allowed as per scriptures.

Here are a couple of relevant verses.

> 8.103. In (some) cases a man who, though knowing (the facts to be) different, **gives such (false evidence) from a pious motive, does not
>   lose heaven; such (evidence) they call the speech of the gods**
>
> 8.104. Whenever the death of a Sudra, of a Vaisya, of a Kshatriya, or of a Brahmana would be (caused) by a declaration of the truth, **a
>   falsehood may be spoken; for such (falsehood) is preferable to the
>   truth.**
>
> **Manu Smriti verses.**

But even for these people (who spoke falsely) some sort of penances are prescribed (in the subsequent Manu Smriti verses) in order to clear the guilt. So, even though speaking falsely is allowed under certain circumstances, some amount of guilt is still attached to the act.