# Is truth a priori to social order?

Tags: vedas

what does the canon say about the clash between truth and social order? Do I let "untruth" exist for the sake of social order and harmony or am I obliged to correct mistakes even if it causes unrest?

Comment: Also see [What is the Hindu (mainly Vedantic) opinion of lying to do good in the world?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29834/2995).

Comment: yes, I appreciate that very much. that certainly does shed light on my concerns. namaste